# Iterating over query results from sqlalchemy

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, sqlalchemy

I have a sqlalchemy query function like this

```
def foo():
local_session = Session()
results = local_session.query(T.x, T.y, T.z, T.a, T.b, T.c
, T.d, T.e, T.f, T.g, T.h, T.i, T.j, T.k, T.l
, T.m, T.n, T.o, T.p, T.q, T.r, T.s, T.t, T.u
, T.v, 
User.gender).join(User)\
.filter(T.language == 'en', T.where_i_am_from == 'US',
User.some_num >= 0.9).limit(1000000)

local_session.close()
return results, results.count()
```

The query works fine.
and then I call this function here:

```
def fubar():

raw_data,raw_data_length = myModule.foo()

df = pd.DataFrame()
for each in raw_data:

    df = df.append(pd.DataFrame({ #add each.x etc to df..... }}


return df
```

The issue is that it wont iterate over the "for each in raw_data" loop when I have a .limit on my foo query above 5000, or use .all() or have no limit. The program will just hang and do nothing (0 cpu usage). I've tested this both on my local sql server and my amazon one. When I run the sql directly on the database I return around 800,000 rows.  Why is this happening?

I'm using the latest mysql and latest sqlalchemy.

Comment: Not an answer to you question, rather a remark to another part of the question: I am not sure this is the most optimal way to create a `DataFrame`. You can try something like `df = pd.read_sql(query.statement, query.session.bind)` instead.

Comment: I would try to replace your `return ...` statement with the following `rows = results.all()\n local_session.close()\n cnt = len(rows)\n return rows, cnt`. My guess is that it has something to do with the session state.

Comment: thanks. I'll look into that pandas method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be like MySQL driver problem. I would do the following in order:

1. Run python with `-v` flag, like `python -v yourprogram.py`.

This has a potential of showing you where the program got stuck.

2. Get those 800,000 results and stick them in SQLite with tables in equivalent schema.

That's relatively cheap to do, all you have to do afterwards is change SQA database string. Obviously, this would show you whether the problem lies with the driver or it's in your code.

3. You're doing a join between two classes (`T`, `User`) - do eager load instead of default lazy load.

If you have 800,000 rows and doing a lazy join, that may be a problem. Add a `joinedload` (`eagerload` in earlier versions of SQLAlchemy) to `options`.

Comment: It was the mysql driver. I was using Oracles MYSQL connector, switched to pymysql and it works.